# QListView setModel problems calling via QMetaObject::invoke

Tags: c++, qt, qlistview

Hi I have a QListView widget displayed correctly on my user interface.

I am registering a callback to a completely separate 3rd party library. This callback will be called on a completely separate thread to my user interface. I need this callback to interact with the QListView widget and set a new data model, so I believe I have to use

```
MyDataModel * model = new MyDataModel( ui->listViewWidget );
QMetaObject::invokeMethod( ui->listViewWidget, "setModel", Q_ARG( MyDataModel *, model ) );
```

However, It doesn't seem to work. i.e. no data is presented in the QListView widget. I've debugged the return value from QMetaObject::invokeMethod and it's returning false which suggests there's no method called "setModel" on the QListView. However, when I arrange for the callback to be called via the user interface thread, i.e. through a pushbutton on_clicked() event and make a call to

```
MyDataModel * model = new MyDataModel( ui->listViewWidget );
ui->listViewWidget->setModel( model );
```

This works perfectly, so there is a "setModel" method on the QListView..

Can someone please help me understand why QMetaObject::invokeMethod isn't working and maybe clear up wether I need to call invokeMethod in this way. i.e. are my thread assumptions correct about it needing to be ran on the event loop thread.

Yours, dazed and confused..
Mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` invokes only slot or signal on the object. Therefore your `setModel` must declared as `slot`. Also `Q_ARG()` takes a type name and a const reference of that type.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Am I right to worry about setting the model from a different thread then or is this safe to do? Or, maybe there's another way to get a method called on the UI event loop.

Comment: If your called  `QMetaObject::invodeMethod` with type of connection as `Qt::QueuedConnection` or `Qt::AutoConnection`, then it will safe to do.

Comment: Ok, I just have to work out the appropriate way to set the model now that you've explained that setModel isn't a signal or slot. I'm sure I'm approaching this the wrong way or it wouldn't be so difficult

Comment: It is not problem for change model of `ListView` in another thread, only if you not blocked main thread. If you add you method `setModel` in queue, main thread handled this without blocking.